# Python statement works for Python2 but not for Python3. What should I change in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, date

In the following statement dictTimeFC has date in the format YYYY-mm.

```
for key,val in sorted(dictTimeFC.items(), key = lambda(x): map(int, x[0].split('-'))):
```

It displays dates in proper order i.e.

```
2020-9
2020-10
```

this code works well with Python2, but not with Python3. It gives the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I need to execute the program with Python3 as there is some code that can work only with Python3.
Pl suggest how to change the above statement so that it works with Python3.

Comment: There is a big difference between python-2 and python-3. You need to learn about their differences and how to change your code to suit both. start [here](https://www.guru99.com/python-2-vs-python-3.html#:~:text=Python%203%20default%20storing%20of,using%20it%20inside%20for%2Dloop.). You should also learn what each Error mean. Now search for "SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python"

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the lambda argument syntax [[PEP-3113]](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) and also convert the result of the map function from an iterable to a list/tuple in order to allow the comparison [[2to3 Migration]](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#map).

```
key = lambda(x): map(int, x[0].split('-'))
```

to

```
key = lambda x: tuple(map(int, x[0].split('-')))
```

Comment: OP says "displays" they may also be using print statements instead of print *functions*.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace `lambda(x):` by `lambda x: =`.